# #warning this method is no longer used (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, compiler-warnings

In my code for an iOS app, when I compile, I see several
warnings that say `#warning this method is no longer used.`

Can someone provide additional detail about what this means? What do I need to do to resolve it (if anything)?

Comment: Someone added a `#warning` macro to the code. It's just that, a warning, added by a developer. Ask the person that added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#warnings` are the custom warning messages in Xcode.

This is not a compiler error but is about reminding you of things you need to do.

Xcode, when compiling an application to run, will pick up the “#warning” flag and display it in the warnings list. 
This could be useful for many reasons like a to do list.

Just check in your code where these warning massages are and do the required changes.